# Socket error - Connection reset by peer

Tags: etl, teradata, informatica

I have a simple housekeeping session that deletes data prior to one month from teradata tables.This is done using SQL transformation.The mapping has logic such that it handles 3 types of files (daily , monthly first week ,monthly -last week).logic for all 3 types is same.Deleting data prior to 1 month.Router is used to handle this.

The session executes properly for low volume of data(daily file) but when the table has higher volume of data in production , it gives below error :

TRANSF_1_1_1> pmsql_50065 [ERROR] ODL error:
 FnName: Close -- [Teradata][Unix system error] Socket error - Connection reset by peer FnName: Execute Direct -- [Teradata][Unix system error]  104 Socket error - Connection reset by peer ODBC call to SQLError failed. .
TRANSF_1_1_1> CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Aug 08 09:45:01 2014]

We have tried re-executing the session but no luck. Weird part is the delete command is being executed in database as we could see data deleted as required but the session is failing.

Please let me know what is the issue here and also the solution.Thank you.

Comment: Can you check the QueryLog for the exact error? In worst case your session gets automatically killed by some workload management rule using too much resources.

Comment: Seems that ODBC is not responding and connection is marked dead. Please try to look in for some Teradata ODBC connector tips.

Comment: there is a warning in the log about DTM size and it suggests certain DTM buffer size to be allocated. If we change DTM buffer size from auto to the suggested value, should that help?

Comment: yes that will help start from 200mb till 2GB you can try.
let us know if it worked or something else